# Put dict into new list based on a key value in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, append

I have data that looks like this:

```
[{'album': 'Lonerism', 
  'song': 'Led Zeppelin (Bonus Track)', 
  'datetime': '2014-12-10 08:03:00', 
  'artist': 'Tame Impala'}, 
 {'album': 'Lonerism', 
  'song': 'Feels Like We Only Go Backwards', 
  'datetime': '2014-12-10 08:00:00', 
  'artist': 'Tame Impala'}, 
 {'album': 'The Suburbs', 
  'song': 'Empty Room', 
  'datetime': '2014-12-10 07:57:00', 
  'artist': 'Arcade Fire'}]
```

If the value for the 'artist' key == x, I want to put the whole dict into a new list  So far, my code returns only a blank list.

```
def Pick_Artist(self, pickartist):
    entries = self.data_to_dict()

    info = []

    for d in entries:
        arts = d['artist'].lower
        if arts == pickartist:
            info.append(d)
        return info
```

Any help would be most appreciated!!

Comment: What does this do? `self.data_to_dict()`

Comment: It returns data formatted like the stuff above: [{'album': 'Lonerism', 'song': 'Led Zeppelin (Bonus Track)', 'datetime': '2014-12-10 08:03:00', 'artist': 'Tame Impala'}]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are storing a *method reference*:

```
arts = d['artist'].lower
```

Because you didn't **call** the method, you only get the method object itself. That'll never be equal to the string in `pickartist`.

Add `()`:

```
arts = d['artist'].lower()
```

Demo:

```
>>> d = {'album': 'Lonerism', 'song': 'Led Zeppelin (Bonus Track)', 'datetime': '2014-12-10 08:03:00', 'artist': 'Tame Impala'}
>>> d['artist'].lower
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x106506e70>
>>> d['artist'].lower == 'tame impala'
False
>>> d['artist'].lower()
'tame impala'
>>> d['artist'].lower() == 'tame impala'
True
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Syntax gets me every time.